# How to replace tag using AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm new in js ajax. I want ajax, because I don't want refresh page.
My template.

**Before.**

```
  <div id="liveData">
     <video onplay="myVid()"><source src="#"></video>
  </div>
```

**After, I need this.**

```
 <div id="liveData">
     <iframe src="#"></iframe> 
 </div>
```

**JS Ajax.**

```
function myVid() {

      $.ajax({
         url : 'my_url_here',
         type:'GET',   
         dataType: 'json',
         cache: false,
            success: function(response) {
               console.log(response)
               $('div#liveData').load(response);
           }

    });
}
```

I see the result in console, but there are no changes in template.

Comment: Here is the [API doc for load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/). **Description:** *Load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched elements.* . Your ajax request is redundant. Simply using `$('#liveData').load('my_url_here')` would suffice.

Comment: Using `.load` to *load* (via AJAX) is the correct approach as above.   In this case, the line `$('div#liveData').load(response);` should probably just be `$('div#liveData').html(response);` to set the html response into the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<div id="liveData">
  <video id="myVideo"><source src="#"></video>
</div>

<script>
  function myVid() {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'my_url_here',
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json',
      cache: false,
      success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        $('#liveData').html(response.html); // load the HTML returned in the response into the liveData div
        $('#myVideo').attr('src', response.video_src); // set the src attribute of the video element to the video URL returned in the response
      }
    });
  }

  $('#myVideo').on('play', function() { // listen for the 'play' event on the video element
    myVid();
  });
</script>
```